# Почему при разрешении телефона в 1920х1080 медиазапрос срабатывает только при min-width: 350px и ниже?

Tags: css

Когда верстал адаптив в сайте на телефоне медиа-запросами встретился с такой странностью - на смартфоне 5.5 дюймов с full hd медиа-запрос `min-width` срабатывает только при значениях 350px и ниже

Почему медиазапрос срабатывает на 350 пикселях а не на 1080?

Comment: Потому что логические пиксели в смартфонах не более 767. Обычно коэффициент 3 или 4. Скорее всего, у вас 3.1080/3 =360

Comment: Используйте dev tools chrome, там указано реальное логическое разрешение на телефонах.